# To-do/task service that can receive SMS messages and send back reminders?

Tags: sms, tasks, reminder

I am aware of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/todo-task-events-webapps-that-send-you-sms-as-reminder), but the services don't seem to have support for receiving SMS messages to set tasks. Ideally, I should be able text a certain number something with the format "stop by Grandma's at 4pm tomorrow" and expect it to relay the message back to me at the time specified.

[Remember the Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) has the Smart Add feature which "intelligently" finds the time in the message, figures out what I mean by "at 4pm tomorrow", and extracts it from the name of the reminder. RTM allows setting reminders by email, but my phone (as well as many others) has trouble correctly sending and receiving emails as SMS messages.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: RTM has a very helpful support team. what is the make of your phone. I am sure you can pass a support request for your phone.

Comment: I believe the email problem has to do with the way my phone service formats emails. If I sent a message containing 160 characters for example, the first 80 (or so) would end up in the subject and all 160 would be sent in the body. However, RTM requires that the complete message is sent in the subject and all tags, locations, and priority levels are put in the body.

This is a problem when the message is long, so if I sent "<lots of characters> next Thursday", RTM might receive it as "<lots of characters> next Thu" and not recognize the date I specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/info/help_twitter.php).  It would use [Twitter](http://support.twitter.com/groups/34-mobile/topics/123-getting-started/articles/14589-how-to-add-your-phone-via-sms) as an intermediary.  You can create a Toodeldo task by sending a DM on Twitter.  You can send Tweets (including DMs) [via SMS](http://support.twitter.com/articles/14020-official-twitter-text-commands).

Comment: But if you are not in USA it's not really working.

Comment: Are you saying you can't sms twitter if not in US?  The twitter page I linked to lists numbers for different countries, so while I can't test it, seems like it should work?

Comment: Ya know, now that you mention it, Twitter is also covered by Remember the Milk. I never use Twitter, but this would give me a chance to make it work.

Comment: Not exactly the perfect situation since it isn't a direct communication, but I'm sure it is easier for Toodledo/RTM/etc to deal with Twitter and let Twitter deal with mobile support.

Comment: actually they added lots of new countries, but there are very few from Europe.. and Denmark is not one of them :D

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: You can now do this more easily in Toodledo, without needing to use Twitter.

Toodledo lets you create a custom e-mail address to send tasks to, but until recently, it rejected e-mails without a subject.  But that has changed; you can now send an e-mail to create a task even if the subject is blank.  See the May 5th, 2012 entry here:

[Toodledo Blog: News, Updates and Changes](http://www.toodledo.com/info/news.php)

Strangely, it currently adds the SMS text to both the item text and the note text.  But that's certainly better than what it did before, which was to ignore e-mails without a subject.